# How to pass GET query parameters in Quarkus as POJO object?

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I'm switching from Spring to Quarkus and this doesn't seem to work the same way.

There are classes defined:

```java
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

  @GET
  public List<String> search(ExampleSearchParams params) {
    Log.info(params);
    return List.of();
  }

}
```

```java
public record ExampleSearchParams(
  String searchQuery,
  Integer size,
  Integer from
) {
}
```

Now after querying URL `/example?size=10` or `/example?size=10&from=10&searchQuery=test` you get HTTP ERROR 415.

Try 1. According to docs, you need to annotate with `@BeanParam`

```java
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

  @GET                    // v HERE
  public List<String> search(@BeanParam ExampleSearchParams params) {
    Log.info(params);
    return List.of();
  }

}
```

Now the Quarkus app fails to start:

```
ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors

[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#validate threw an exception: jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Found 3 deployment problems: 

[1] Unsatisfied dependency for type java.lang.String and qualifiers [@Default]

[2] Unsatisfied dependency for type java.lang.Integer and qualifiers [@Default]

[3] Unsatisfied dependency for type java.lang.Integer and qualifiers [@Default]
```

Try 2. Add `@RestQuery` annotations

```java
public record ExampleSearchParams(
  @RestQuery
  String searchQuery,
  @RestQuery
  Integer size,
  @RestQuery
  Integer from
) {
}
```

Still the same error on Quarkus app startup.

Try 3. Use `@RestQuery` directly on object parameter.

```java
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

  @GET
  public List<String> search(@RestQuery ExampleSearchParams params) {
    Log.info(params);
    return List.of();
  }

}
```

And the Quarkus app fails to start with error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create converter for ExampleSearchParams for method java.util.List<java.lang.String> search()
```

In pom.xml there is dependency

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Any workaround for this?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#grouping-parameters-in-a-custom-class. Also https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** BeanParams are not working with Java Records yet.

Quarkus 3 supports Jakarta EE APIs. The latest JakartaEE 10 specification contains Restful Web Services 3.1 component which is on Java 11.

According to this [discussion on JakartaEE's GitHub project](https://github.com/jakartaee/rest/issues/913) v4.0 will be supporting Java 17 (or later)

Using traditional java class will solve this problem

```java
public class ExampleSearchParameters {
    @QueryParam("query")
    String searchQuery;
    @QueryParam("page_size")
    Integer size;
    @QueryParam("page_index")
    Integer from;
}
```

**Don't forget** to put annotations on fields (e.g. `@QueryParam`).

Now, this POJO can be injected as a `@BeanParam` like this:

```java
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    public List<String> hello(@BeanParam ExampleSearchParameters filterParams) {
        return List.of("query:" + filterParams.searchQuery, "size: " + filterParams.size, "from:" + filterParams.from);
    }
}
```