# Quarkus RestClient @BeanParam equivalent

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a case where I have a search endpoint with many possible parameters. On the server side, I have a `@BeanParam` keeping the method signature sane.

I would like similar functionality, to use a pojo to specify the possible params and not have to include them all in the method signature. Is there a way to do this?

```
    @GET
    Set<Extension> getByFilter(@RestQuery Map<String, String> filter);
```

seems close, but I would rather specify an actual pojo rather than deal with making a map.

Comment: you can make the pojo like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76766011/175554)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@BeanParam` is definitely works on client side.

##### Configuring OpenapiTools to generate parameters as `@BeanParam`

A sample endpoint which allows a custom headper parameter `X-Custom-Header` and three query params like: `filter_name`, `filter_age`, `filter_active` is documented like:

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: so-77975157-quarkus-client-beanparam API
  version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
paths:
  /api:
    get:
      tags:
      - Example Resource
      parameters:
      - name: filter_active
        in: query
        schema:
          type: boolean
      - name: filter_age
        in: query
        schema:
          format: int32
          type: integer
      - name: filter_name
        in: query
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: X-Custom-Header
        in: header
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                uniqueItems: true
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
```

By default Openapi Generator will create a method and that's signature will contain every parameter one by one.

```java
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Set<String> filter(@HeaderParam("X-Custom-Header") String headerParam,
                          @QueryParam("filter_name") String nameFilter,
                          @QueryParam("filter_age") Integer ageFilter,
                          @QueryParam("filter_active") Boolean activeFilter);
```

Using the following plugin configuration will generate interfaces using one parameter object annotated by `@BeanParam`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <cleanupOutput>true</cleanupOutput>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
                <additionalProperties>disableMultipart=true</additionalProperties>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>

                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <library>microprofile</library>
                <configOptions>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <useJakartaEe>true</useJakartaEe>
                    <configKey>myclient</configKey>
                    <serializationLibrary>jackson</serializationLibrary>
                    <useSingleRequestParameter>true</useSingleRequestParameter>
                    <microprofileRestClientVersion>3.0</microprofileRestClientVersion>
                    <useRuntimeException>true</useRuntimeException>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Note #1** the magic is `useSingleRequestParameter` configuration option.

**Note #2** there are some hidden trap in the built-in template. E.g. an unvanted Apache CXF import definition which may cause compile errors. So, `<additionalProperties>disableMultipart=true</additionalProperties>` property is important to set.

Now, the generated method signature will be:

```java
@GET
@Produces({ "application/json" })
Set<String> apiGet(@BeanParam ApiGetRequest request) throws ApiException, ProcessingException;
```

and the `ApiGetRequest` (sorry for that name, I didn't use operationId and/or tags in the sample)

```java
public class ApiGetRequest {

    private @QueryParam("filter_active") Boolean filterActive;
    private @QueryParam("filter_age") Integer filterAge;
    private @QueryParam("filter_name") String filterName;
    private @HeaderParam("X-Custom-Header")  String xCustomHeader;

    private ApiGetRequest() {
    }

    public static ApiGetRequest newInstance() {
        return new ApiGetRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Set filterActive
     * @param filterActive  (optional)
     * @return ApiGetRequest
     */
    public ApiGetRequest filterActive(Boolean filterActive) {
        this.filterActive = filterActive;
        return this;
    }
    /**
     * Set filterAge
     * @param filterAge  (optional)
     * @return ApiGetRequest
     */
    public ApiGetRequest filterAge(Integer filterAge) {
        this.filterAge = filterAge;
        return this;
    }
    /**
     * Set filterName
     * @param filterName  (optional)
     * @return ApiGetRequest
     */
    public ApiGetRequest filterName(String filterName) {
        this.filterName = filterName;
        return this;
    }
    /**
     * Set xCustomHeader
     * @param xCustomHeader  (optional)
     * @return ApiGetRequest
     */
    public ApiGetRequest xCustomHeader(String xCustomHeader) {
        this.xCustomHeader = xCustomHeader;
        return this;
    }
}
```

On the server side the registered client will be available.

```java
@Path("/foobar")
public class ServerSideResource {

    @RestClient
    ExampleResourceApi clientApi;

    @GET
    public Set<String> callSampleClient() {
        return clientApi.apiGet(ApiGetRequest.newInstance()
                .filterActive(true)
                .filterName("zforgo")
        );
    }

}
```

However, Openapi Generator can generate functions with a single argument it has lack of utilization capabilities (like inheritance, reuse common parts, etc.)

Fortunately JakartaEE standard supports that, but it has to be created manually.

##### Creating more complex API manually

```java
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "person-api")
public interface PersonClient {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    FilterResult<PersonDTO> search(@HeaderParam("X-Custom-Header") String headerParam,
                                   @BeanParam PersonFilter personFilter,
                                   @BeanParam PagingAndSorting pagingAndSorting);


}
```

As you can see, the result type is generic and paging and sorting capabilities are utilized to a separated argument.

PagingAndSorting:

```java
public class PagingAndSorting {
    public static final String param_PageIndex = "page_index";
    public static final String param_PageSize = "page_size";
    public static final String param_SortCriteria = "sort_criteria";
    public static final String param_SortDirection = "sort_direction";

    private static final String directionAscending = "Ascending";
    public static final String pageUnlimited = "-1";

    @QueryParam(param_SortCriteria)
    public Optional<String> sortingCriteria;

    @QueryParam(param_SortDirection)
    @DefaultValue(directionAscending)
    public Sort.Direction sortDirection;

    @QueryParam(param_PageIndex)
    public int pageIndex;

    @QueryParam(param_PageSize)
    @DefaultValue(pageUnlimited)
    public int pageSize;

    // getters, setters, builder ...
}
```

PersonFilter:

```java
public class PersonFilter {

    @QueryParam("filter_name")
    private String nameFilter;

    @QueryParam("filter_age")
    private Integer ageFilter;

    @QueryParam("filter_active")
    private Boolean activeFilter;

    // getters, setters, builder ...
}
```

FilterResult:

```java
public class FilterResult<T> {
    private final Pagination pagination;
    private final List<T> items;

    public FilterResult(List<T> items, Pagination pagination) {
        this.items = items;
        this.pagination = pagination;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public FilterResult(List<T> items, long totalCount, Integer pageCount, Integer pageIndex) {
        this(items, new Pagination(totalCount, pageCount, pageIndex));
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public Pagination getPagination() {
        return pagination;
    }

    public FilterResult<T> withPageSize(Integer pageSize) {
        pagination.pageSize = pageSize;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Pagination:

```java
public class Pagination {

    protected long totalCount;
    protected Integer pageCount;
    protected Integer pageIndex;

    protected Integer pageSize;

    public Pagination(long totalCount, Integer pageCount, Integer pageIndex) {
        this.totalCount = totalCount;
        this.pageCount = pageCount;
        this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    }

    public long getTotalCount() {
        return totalCount;
    }

    public Integer getPageCount() {
        return pageCount;
    }

    public Integer getPageIndex() {
        return pageIndex;
    }
}
```

Finally the server side code sample:

```java
@Path("/check")
public class ServerSideResource {

    @RestClient
    PersonClient personApi;

    @GET
    @Path("/person-search")
    public FilterResult<PersonDTO> searchPerson() {
        return personApi.search("FooBar",
                // create and fill PersonFilter
                personFilter()
                        .filterActive(true)
                        .filterName("zforgo"),
                // create and fill PagingAndSorting
                pagingAndSorting()
                        .pageSize(20)
                        .sortCriteria("name")
                        .sortDirection(Sort.Direction.Ascending)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming it works, for some lombok-related reasons it was failing to work, but looks good now.